# How can I extract data from lines and add new lines with extracted data?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a source code and I want to replace some specific lines with a new formatting and text.

Following lines are in a file:

```
LogIfYouCan(!is_it_ready, "Log Text, some variable: " << variable1 << " variable2: " << variable2);
```

I want to replace it with

```
if(!is_it_ready) {
   LogOutput("Log Text, some variable: " << variable1 << " variable2: " << variable2);
}
```

That means, lines beginning with `LogIfYouCan` will be changed to `LogOutput` with the text after `,` until the end of line and text from `(` to comma `,` will be added in `if` with curly braces.
How can I do it? With `sed`, `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[^!]*([^,]*),[^"]*(.*)/if(\1) {\n   LogOutput(\2\n}/' input_file
if(!is_it_ready) {
   LogOutput("Log Text, some variable: " << variable1 << " variable2: " << variable2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sed that supports `-E` to enable EREs and `\n` for newlines such as GNU sed and BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/^LogIfYouCan\(([^,]+), *(.*)/if(\1) {\n   LogOutput(\2\n}/' file
if(!is_it_ready) {
   LogOutput("Log Text, some variable: " << variable1 << " variable2: " << variable2);
}
```